# AWS S3 PHP SDK V3 how to go directly to specific "folder" in bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been trying to learn this SDK and im starting to understand it, but one issue I cant seem to figure out is how do I go directly to a "folder" (I know there are not folders) in the bucket?
In my bucket I have "folder1", using getIterator('ListObjects',... all I get is the root of the bucket showing "folder1" instead of root of "folder1".
I have used the 'Prefix' and 'Delimiter' but i guess I am missing something.

Here's I got, any help is appreciated.

```
$s3 = new S3Client([
'version'     => 'latest',
'region'      => 'us-east-1',
'credentials' => [
    'key'    => $config['s3']['key'],
    'secret' => $config['s3']['secret'],
],]);
        $objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
            'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'],
            'Prefix' => $config['s3']['folder1']."/",
            'Delimiter' => "/",

            ));
                          foreach($objects as $object):...
```

What am I missing here?

```
<?php 

                        $i = 0; $y = 1;
                         $imgExts = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'tiff', 'tif', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp', 'svg');
                         $videoExts = array('mp4', 'avi', 'mpg', 'mpeg', '3gp', 'mov', 'mkv');
                         $folderArr = array(); // array of the folders get from the List object 
                          //foreach($objects as $object):
                            //foreach($objects['Contents'] as $object):

                                foreach ($objects as $result) {
                                    // You can extract any data that you want from the result.
                                    foreach ($result['Contents'] as $object):

                            $size = $size+$object['Size'];
                            $filepath = $object['Key'];
                            echo $filepath;
                            $tmp = explode("/", $filepath); // object key is exploded by "/" to get check whether it is a file or a directory.
                            //echo $tmp;
                            $filename = array_pop($tmp); // return last element from array, it will be file name or blank value

                            $directoryPath = implode("/", $tmp)."/"; // implode array using "/" to get directory of the object

                            $SubFolderPath = str_replace(".php","",$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                            $tmpFol = explode("/",trim($directoryPath, "/"));
                            $subDir = array_pop($tmpFol);
                            $rootDir = implode("/", $tmpFol)."/";
                            //echo $tmpFol;
                            if(!empty($filename)):
                                $img = "";
                                $ext = array_pop(explode(".", $filename));
                                if(in_array(strtolower(trim($ext)), $imgExts)):
                                    $img = "fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg";
                                    //$img = $s3->getObjectUrl($config['s3']['bucket'], $filepath);
                                elseif(in_array(strtolower(trim($ext)), $videoExts)):
                                    $img = "fa fa-video-camera";

                                else:
                                    $img = "fa fa-file-text-o";
                                endif;
                            endif;

                            $fileContent = '<tr class="file-sort" data-name="'.strtolower($filename).'" data-date="'.date("Y-m-d", strtotime($object['LastModified'])).'>" data-size="'.$object['Size'].'">
                                <td>'.$y.'</td>
                                <td><i class="'.$img.'"></i> '.$filename.'</td>
                                <!--<td><a href="'.$img.'" data-lightbox="image-set" data-title="'.strtolower($filename).'" ><img src="'.$img.'"style="width:65px;height:60px;cursor:zoom-in;" class="center_image"><span style="cursor:zoom-in">'.$filename.'</span></td>-->
                                <td>'.date("M j Y, g:i A", strtotime($object['LastModified'])).'</td>
                                <td>'.formatBytes($object['Size'], 0).'</td>  
                                <td>
                                <a href="download_file.php?key='.$s3->getObjectUrl($config['s3']['bucket'], $filepath).'" download="'.$filename.'" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i></a>
```

Comment: Try changing the "/" to "\" and see if it works?

Comment: The above should find all of `folder1/any-filename` but not `folder1/another1/file` or `folder1/another1/andhere2/file` etc.  Are there files directly "under" folder1, or just more "folders?"

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot under folder1 there are more folders and files, like this: folder1/photos, folder1/photos/wallpapers, folder1/videos/1080p and some misc files in the root of folder1.

Comment: I wanted to add, maybe clarify, that the concept is to have all users in one bucket and a "folder" for each user, when user signs on they are directed to the root of their assigned folder listing its contents,  right now the user signs on and sees their folder listed and has to click it to get into it.

Comment: "has to click to get into it" -- so, there's something you are doing that makes it work on the second attempt?  How do the parameters of the second request (generated by the user clicking on it?) differ from the parameters of the original request?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, yes i have a "filtering' process to differentiate between "folders" and files.

Comment: Okay, but you're implying that you're sending a second request to S3 when the user clicks on their folder, at which point you get the expected behavior from S3.  How does that request differ from the one in the question, which you say isn't returning contents as expected?

Comment: That's the wierd part, when i click  folder1, url (http://domain.com/files?prefix=binarysilo%2F) that triggers the second iteration which inst much different from the first iteration. I just cant make sense of it. Heres the second iteration:  $objects = $s3->getPaginator('ListObjects', array(
  'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'],
     'Prefix' => $_REQUEST['prefix']
 ));